# Booking Engine Payment Gateway Logic

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, payment-gateway

I am developing a booking engine in node js & Parse for a hotel website. In this I am checking for availability twice. Once when user fills all booking details and other before going to payment gateway. The payment gateway (CCAvenue) has success and cancel URL where they post data as per users behaviour. But the problem here is that if the tab is closed by the user there is no event called by the payment gateway. I can open this payment gateway page in new tab. But still I want the booking id of the booking cancelled due to tab close.
NOTE: I am creating booking with PENDING status and updating the status to ACTIVE when payment is successful.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler answer is to update to PENDING status and also a "Pending Expire DateTime".  Make this whatever works for your business.  Maybe 1 Hour.

Then if they have NOT posted a payment successfully within one hour then you change the PENDING to "FailedDeposit" and allow the room to be booked again.

Make sure your user is aware of that they have to pay deposit and do NOT give them a confirmation until after the payment is received.  The user doesn't need to know that you are holding the room for them.  They should believe that they are not confirmed until they pay.